# name of pandas dataframe contains dot - What to do?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this list of listed companies at the stock market:

```
german_list = ['DTE.DE','DAI.DE','HOT.DE','WDI.DE']
```

I read them in to get a pandas dataframe using this code:

```
for stock in german_list:
  globals()[stock] = data.DataReader(stock,'yahoo',start,end)
```

The name of one of the dataframes is for example `DTE.DE`. How can I rename or access this dataframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
german_list = ['DTE.DE','DAI.DE','HOT.DE','WDI.DE']
stocks = { stock : data.DataReader(stock,'yahoo', start, end) for stock in german_list }
```

You can then access the data, by doing:

```
stocks['DTE.DE']
```